# P-channel MOSFET saturation biasing condition

Tags: mosfet

In PMOS netlist shown below, for the MOSFET to start conducting 
Vt=-0.39 V 
Vgs < Vt = -0.39 
0-1.8 < -0.39 
I want to understand how to make it in conducting state, with linear and saturation 
from the formula shown below we need Vdg<-(-0.39) to make saturation.
Vg=0.4 so Vd<-0.4+0.4=0 is the condition for saturation.
However, as you can see below I got the linear and saturation states flipped.
Where did I go wrong in my mathematical condition for saturation?

https://sanjayvidhyadharan.in/Downloads/tsmc_180_nm/tsmc018.lib

[http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/psd/L10/pmosfet/pmosfet.html](http://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/psd/L10/pmosfet/pmosfet.html)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a P-channel MOSFET your gate voltage must be applied between gate and source: -

[image]

Comment: Hello Andy, Could you please look at my plot and see where did i go wrong with the saturation math condition?

Comment: Why haven't you followed my advice (as stated in my answer) @lub2354

Comment: because you are connecting two voltage sources at the same node.their pluses are on the same node.

Comment: If I called that common node ground would you understand better.

Comment: Its a good method to see the threshold voltage.

but i am looking for switching between linear and saturation.

Comment: @lub2354 think about this... how would you make a circuit for an n-channel MOSFET that does what you want?

Comment: Hello Andy i have implemented you remark in a new question because i didnt know how to post picture in a comment.could you please say in that question where my math goes wrong? thanks.

Comment: I'm dealing with this question before moving on to your newer question so, concentrate on what I advised about the n-channel MOSFET and how you'd connect that up.

Comment: @lub2354 - Hi, Re: "*i have implemented you remark in a new question*" No! Please don't do that. It splits effort into multiple places & causes confusion & frustration for others. Now you have caused a mess by getting answers to the new question too, instead of getting clarification here :( I can't fix it, even as a mod, since mods can't move answers between questions :( || In future, to add images in a comment, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded