# P-channel MOSFET saturation condition: math contradiction

Tags: mosfet

I am using a P-channel MOSFET with Vt = -0.4 and Vgs > -0.4 => Vs = 0 Vg > 0 always so it's not supposed to conduct.

Vdg > -Vt = +0.4 for the linear state.

At V2 = 0.2 our plot is linear state, but mathemetically I get the opposite: Vdg = 0.2-1.8 > -(-0.4) = 0.4 FALSE.

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Closely related question raised by the OP yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659994/p-channel-mosfet-saturation-biasing-condition-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threshold voltage Vt is -0.4V.
Vgs is held constant at -1.2V, below the theshold voltage. A sweep of Vds from 0 to -1.8V is performed. The drain current is plotted against Vds.

The plot shows the transition from linear to saturation regions as Vds decreases from 0 to -1.8V.

Vgs-Vt is -0.8V (1.2 - 0.4), the plot also suggests a transition about -0.8 volts.

Vds = -0.2V is within the linear region, as it is greater than -0.8v (Vgs - Vt).

Comment: Hello Liam,thanks you for the explanation i have written it thurelly bellow very helpfull.

One question,How do i see in LTspice model where is the source  of my MOSFET in NMOS and PMOS?
Thanks.
Vgs<=-0.4 conduction: \
Vs-Vg=1.2 => Vgs=-1.2 \
Vds>Vgs-Vt \
Vds>-1.2-(-0.4) \
Vsd=0..1.8 \
Vds=0..-1.8 \
Vds>-1.2+0.4=-0.8 \
so for Vds=-0.2 is in linear \\

Comment: The source is connected to the positive side of V2. The gate is connected to the negative side of V1. The drain is connected to the common refrence point (you might call "ground"). In a PMOS symbol, the arrow of the body diode point away from the gate terminal. In NMOS the arrow points toward the gate.

Comment: Hello Liam,Its a netlist thing. I know that NMOS and PMOS have opposite Source location.
Generally speaking in real life  NMOS and PMOS are simmetric devices and SOURCE and drain are determined by where is the higher voltage.

But in LTSPICE i assume its not like in real world :-) ?
in PMOS we can put the VDS voltage source one way and then to reverse its ,unlike real life the Drain and source will not be switched?

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly know what you are doing here.. But

The voltage between gate and source is fixed by V1, in your drawing 1.2V, so Vgs is always -1.2V. You show an equation for Vdg, which I don't understand. Isn't Vdg V1-V2?. Then when V2 = 0.2 Vdg is 1V.